# When do task based applications switch context?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, task, vxworks

Let's say you had two tasks. Each one has it's own complex modules running schedule based systems and event based systems. When thinking about context switching, exactly when and how does a task scheduler decide when to switch tasks, and at one point can it do this? Will a task switch while in the middle of executing a block of code? Right in the middle of a function?

For reference I am working in a vxworks environment.

Comment: some of the times when a task switch is performed:  1) when the time-slice expires 2) when the task performs any I/O  3) when a task calls a 'context switch' function  4) when a higher priority task becomes 'ready'  5) when a running task exits   The list goes on and on

Comment: Can it happen while in the middle of a function?

Comment: a context switch can happen between any instruction and the next and during certain repetitive instructions.

Comment: Could you then use aquire a pointer to shared memory in one instruction, say, `p = GetGlobalPtr()` and then before being able to even use it `p->Do();` have it become null or otherwise invalid?

Comment: those are two statements.  Statements result (most of the time) in many instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, operating system schedules have no concern for blocks of C code. They switch when various events occur including:

- A timer measuring how long your process has been using the CPU expires.
- A device connected to the computer reports it has completed a task, and some process with high priority than yours was waiting for this.
- Your process makes a request that cannot be satisfied immediately, such as requesting input from the keyboard, and the user has not typed it yet.

In the last case, the switch of course occurs at the point of your request. The others are effectively random with regard to where your process is executing. The associated interrupt can occur at any instruction in your process.

In some processor architectures, an interrupt can even occur **during** certain instructions: The instruction may be interrupted when it has only been partially executed, and the registers will be updated so that execution can be resumed to continue the instruction later.

Comment: Could you please give a particular example of an architecture mentioned in the last paragraph?

Comment: @Evg: [ARM has some restartable instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31114349/what-is-interruptible-restartable-instructions-in-arm-cortex-m0-m0), but I was thinking of a move-multiple-bytes instruction. I cannot remember which architecture it was on! IBM System 360? As I recall, it moved C bytes from A to B and left the registers adjusted for a future move—A and B advanced by C bytes and C decremented to zero. So it could be interrupted by writing the current pointers and count to A, B, and C, and then restarting execution of the instruction would resume at the interrupt point.